# Ubuntu 15 desktop files outside main area

Tags: virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu 15 installation running on VirtualBox with Guest Additions installed. When I right click on the Desktop and choose "Organize Desktop by Name" some of the files go to the top of the Desktop over the border and I cannot see them. It also happens when I save a file from a browser, it goes over the top border. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by going to Settings > Displays and I realized the 2 screens were not aligned. I just drag and dropped the left screen to be aligned with the right one and everything is back to normal.

[Align displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkFbN.png)